# yagi antenna gain formula

Tags: antenna, gain

is there any specific formula to calculate yagi-uda antenna Gain? i know that The Gain of Yagi Antenna depends on length of antenna array and do not depend on number of directors used in the design , but how can i calculate it?

Comment: There's no formula - each design has to be optimised. But SM5BSZ has done a fantastic job in this paper. Perhaps fit a line in the form of G=x+y.log(length/wavelength)  from the final graph. http://www.sm5bsz.com/antennas/cpudes01.htm

Comment: Directional gain is certainly related to the number of directors - they determine the lobe pattern. Remember the absolute radiated power is constant; a directional antenna affects how that power is distributed around the polar plot.